# HMTL mailto form

Tags: html, forms, mailto

I'm trying to create a simple HTML page that an internal user can enter details and then it will open an Outlook email so they can send the fields to a designated address.
I have been able to set the email address and subject using the mailto function but in the body of the email I want to add in the values from the different fields.
I can only get 1 field into the body of the email at this time.

```
<form action="mailto:email@company.com" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
<label for="cname">Company name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="cname" name="cname"><br>

<label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>

<label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname"><br>

<label for="email">Email Address:</label><br>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br>

<br>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Interest1" name="Interest1" value="Interest1"
<label for="Interest1">TradeMarks</label<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Interest2" name="Interest2" value="Interest2"
<label for="Interest2">Patents</label<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Interest3" name="Interest3" value="Interest3"
<label for="Interest3">Design</label<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Interest4" name="Interest4" value="Interest4"
<label for="Interest4">Christmas Card</label<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="Interest5" name="Interest5" value="Interest5"
<label for="Interest5">Calendar</label<br><br>
<br>
<br>

 <a href="mailto:email@company.com?Subject=Add Client&body=cname" >Send Email</a>



 </form>

 </html>
```

Comment: You can't this with HTML. Your `<a>` is not connected to the form data. This usually is done with server side code, PHP, ASP, etc.